# Setting fields to readonly in dynamics crm 2013 business process flows

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have a business process flow that a customer wants to use cosmetically. All the stages are only on one entity. The customer wants certain look up fields to be read-only. What I've discovered is that while I can disable fields in the active stage of the business process flow using Xrm.Page, users can access other stages and enter data however they like. I haven't been able to find a supported method of making lookup fields readonly in non-active stages. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try put the following code in the OnLoad event of the Form:

```
// Get the field in BPF
var c = Xrm.Page.getControl("header_process_<your field name>");
if (c != null) {
    c.setDisabled(true);
}
```

Hope it helps!